# Mono System.TypeLoadException

Tags: .net, mono

I have created a C# Socket server and when i try to run it on Linux (have Mono Runtime installed) i get this exception every time the socket initializes

`System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'`

Project Information:

- Target Framework: `.Net 4.5`.
- Type: `Console Application`.
- External Dependencies: `None`.
- Compiled Using: `Normal Visual Studio Compiler`.

Note: This only happens on Linux `Ubuntu`, while working fine on windows.

Comment: What is your Mono version? The Ubuntu repositories have old ones which do not support the full .NET 4 framework, if I recall.

Answer (score 1):

Default references in Visual Studio and MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio are different. `mscorlib` should always be referenced, but I think compiling the project in Linux host would make it work:

    `$ cd /path/to/source
    $ xbuild
    $ mono bin/your.exe`